# Will a PIVOT meet my requirements?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (PersonNo int, Name varchar, Age int,address varchar(100))
```

Is it possible to SELECT the data in the following format using a single query:

```
PersonNo Name
PersonNo Age
PersonNo Address
```

I would need a column to identify the type of row e.g. Name.  The more I think about this the more I don't think I can do it.  I am currently trying to do it with a pivot.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use `UNION ALL` (just remember to convert the `int` to `varchar`):

```
select personno, name as value, 'Name' as type
from person
union all 
select personno, CONVERT(varchar(10), age), 'Age' as type
from person
union all 
select personno, address, 'Address' as type
from person
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/feedb/1)

Also please note -- you should define a length for the `Name` field.  As is, it can only contain a single character.

Comment: Yes I believe that is what I was looking for. +1. I will wait until tomorrow before accepting in case there are more answers.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for an [`UNPIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28SQL.105%29.aspx), not a `PIVOT`

```
SELECT
  PersonNo
 ,ColumnName
 ,ColumnValue
FROM Person t1
UNPIVOT(ColumnValue FOR ColumnName in ([Name],[Age],[Address])) t2
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test this in the morning and get back to you.

Comment: This option can work, but you'll need to use a subquery and convert the  columns to the same data type.